# Flash to HTML5 site building advice required?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, unity-game-engine

I've used and trusted Flash for over a decade but as it seems that the world is slowly turning on it, it's seems fair to assume that at the very least it makes good sense to convert any new ideas into a more accepted medium.

By working on a new site and/or converting a new project for HTML5, is it a wise move to restructure internal design and coding to inline coding with frame based animation etc so to be able to maximise it's potential with Javasscript coding etc?

Package based classes will obviously become redundant and using multi sectional media seems to me to be unusable in this way, am I right in thinking this?

Also, having played with Unity3D, is it a viable solution to think that you could create a full interactive website in the same manner as with Flash previously and incorporate galleries and or coded interactive medie to feature within or as an overlay in this manner? Also would it be possible to fuse a Unity based site with interactive media to reference galleries or alternative ways of displaying media, so if I designed a 3d shop and incorporated various sections to activate (for example) the help section, Q & A, and any other sections whereby I'd like to have an as3 feature activated to view, either as a pop up or an onscreen overlay etc?

Any help to this would be gratefully recieved as it seems that with the lack of forward support from Adobe with regards to Flash, it is slowly being killed off and lacking a stable reason for people to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Adobe Edge Animate and Google Web Designer. You can also learn TypeScript which is similar to ActionScript3 in many ways (but it is a superset of javascript and transcompiles idiomatically into javascript)

Comment: On a side note, I would really not recommend using Unity in the way that Flash has been used in the past to create entire sites, lest you run into the same problems with screen readers, SEO, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> is it a wise move to restructure internal design [...] to maximise it's potential with Javascript coding etc?

Yes since as you said flash is being forgotten, all browser's R&D will concentrate on other technologies.

So I would recommend you to consider using SVG with HTML5 instead, here is why:

Unity3D is a wonderful game engine, but I thing that for your use it's a bit overkill: Unity3D is designed to make video games, so avoid it if you just want simple interactions, no shaders, no AI, no particles, no physics and such. Unused features = heavier project.
As a side note, users would even need to install a plugin, have a rather good graphic card and processor, etc.
To resume it's like chopping a tree with a bazooka: it's too expensive.

You have alternatives to it like Three.js or a myriad of others WebGL based frameworks. Since they use WebGL they are future oriented and natively supported by modern browsers.
Three.js is lightweight, powerful and easy to use for exemple.
These lightweighted framework are ideal to **be** an interactive media, but as Unity they are an opaque bloc to the eyes of browser, just like an image (as @Serlite said)

It seems you want a Framework interacting with HTML elements via javascript and with plugable medias, so just use HTML5 and SVG for graphics and animation.
You want an interactive media, let's say a flash media? Just add it to your website, just as before but inside the `<svg>` tag.

It's vector graphic, widely used, it has a lot of frameworks and editors, is lightweight, powerful and free.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

(This was too long for a comment.)

While Flash Player was (is) a single technology that can basically do anything with a unified API on every platform it was supported on, the same cannot be said about the web browser. There's an alphabet soup of different technologies with different specs and different strengths and weaknesses, including SVG, DOM, CSS, Canvas, WebGL, JavaScript, transpiled JavaScript from [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) or ES7, and of course [many](http://todomvc.com/), [*many*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) popular use-case specific libraries built on top of these technologies that essentially require their own syntax, project structure, and special library expertise. And don't forget all the related development frameworks like NPM, SASS, Bower, Gulp, Grunt, etc.

In other words, there's no silver bullet, it depends a lot on what you are trying to do. This is why there are no really good visual authoring tools out there, and it will be hard IMO for there ever to be a such a tool that equals what Flash and Flash Player offered. Ironically, [Flash is probably the best visual HTML5 authoring tool out there](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html), if using Canvas (via [CreateJS library](http://www.createjs.com/)) is your ideal solution (good for creative game-like experiences, not so good for content oriented websites.) Still, you'll likely combine Flash's canvas output with other libraries for the whole experience.

**TL;DR** - There's no good one-size-fits all answer, it depends a lot on what you actually want to do, and will almost certainly involve a special combination of several technologies and libraries.